# How can I change URL string for home page in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In ASP.NET MVC 5 project, I have a page which is home page. This page includes form element which causes GET request like below that.

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input name="test" value="deneme" />
    <button type="submit">Click me!</button>
}
```

Controller code is below that;

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyTodoApp.Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : MyTodoAppControllerBase
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

When I click on the submit button, the page go to server with GET method request. But browser URL is changing after this home page request. On other pages doesn't cause this behaviour. Ok, I am understanding because home page is default route page. I don't want to changing URL string for this page with GET method request.

Does anyone have knowledge on this issue?

Comment: What do you mean changing? From what to what?

Comment: First time home page url is "http://localhost/Home/Index". After click on submit button url is being "http://localhost" only. MVC is changing url string for home page. I don't want to it. I didn't prevent this behaivor.

Comment: The change your default route

Comment: It doesn't mather. This situtation is MVC behaivor or Browser behaivor? I don't know. Maybe browser does it. I use i18N localization and i18N is adding prefix "/en/.." or "/de/..". So, in page of default route you make submit with GET method using Html.BeginForm helper. Request redirecting "/en/en..." and redirecting doesn't work. Because url is changing on GET request. For example,  "/Home/Index" to "/" . I didn't think about this issue. :(

Comment: If your RouteConfig file says that the default controller is Home and action is Index, then the URL will result to localhost because of those parameters.